# Codeigniter, force download returns data not download panel

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, download

I want to export my data from database to csv. Here is my code

```
public function export_product_to_csv()
{
    $response = new stdClass();
    $response->success = TRUE;
    $response->message = "Terjadi kesalah saat proses export. Silakan hubungin administartor";
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $filename = "list_item.csv";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `list_item` ";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
    $download = force_download($filename, $data);
    if ($download) {
        $response->message = "Export Berhasil ";
        $response->link = $this->generate_activity_link("view_product_management","Export Product");
        $response->success = TRUE;
    } else {
        $response->message = "Gagal . Query salah.";
    }
  return $response;   
}
```

But when I execute the code it returns

> "item_id","item_code","type_id","ref_number","item_name","price","qty_perpack","label_code","client_id" "1","RL30CM","5"," ","Pengaris 30 Cm","1500","150","TX30CM","0" "2","VP00","5","","Ventplug dengan karet ","2000","2000","TXVP0","1" "3","PP Merah","1","","Bahan coba","15000","","","0" "4","TNVA","5"," ","Antena Tv","15000","1000","TXTVNA","2" "5","YZHAA","5","","Test barang ","1500","1000","TEST","2" "6","YHASA","5","","Pengaris 20 Cm","2000","1000","UZYA","2" "7","PP Hitam","1","","PP Hitam","15000","","","0" "8","PP002","1","","Biji plastik hijau ","200000","","PPGR","2" "9","BBW","4","","Bubble Wrapper","75000","","","0"

not download panel. please help me

Comment: are you outputting other stuff on the same request?  Do you have error reporting on? etc.

Comment: no it just return the csv string no error message or other stuff

Comment: What you are seeing indicates to me that you probably output something before sending the download headers.  For example your CSV data is sent, just the headers are not to tell the browser to download.  And basically if you output anything even a line return, it kills the headers.  But if you have `error_reporting(-1)` and display errors on you would see that.  But I do see a lot of this stuff `$response->message = "Terjad`

Comment: Additionally unless the download happens in a separate request any output will wind up in your file, its just how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method and arrange it as per your requirements. i have used it many times  and it worked for me all the time

```
//get records from database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM list_item ORDER BY id DESC");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "file_name_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

    //create a file pointer
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

    //set column headers
    $fields = array('ID', 'Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Created', 'Status');
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

    //output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $status = ($row['status'] == '1')?'Active':'Inactive';
        $lineData = array($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['email'], $row['phone'], $row['created'], $status);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }

    //move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);

    //set headers to download file rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    //output all remaining data on a file pointer
    fpassthru($f);
}
```